# Long falling edge of a VCSEL laser's pulses

Tags: switching, driver, bandwidth, vcsel

I've been trying to drive a 940nm VCSEL (Part No. V105Q131A-940) with an iC-Haus HG20M VCSEL driver. When given short pulsed signals (pulsewidth of ~100us), the optical signals detected by a photodetector (ThorLabs DET10C2) shows strange behaviours, see graph below:
[image]

Where "photodiode" refers to the read-out from the photodiode, that's directly connected to the oscilloscope, and "VPOT12" refers to the voltage at the VCSEL driver which controls the amount of current at the VCSEL cathode.

Somehow the pulse's falling edges seems very capacitive. Please ignore the values on the x-axis as they are not temporal, but I can confirm that the actual pulsewidths matches what's expected until pulsewidths less than 12us, where the signal looses it's form completely.

I can tell at least two issues there, namely:

- The falling edges' strange behaviour.
- There seems to be a bandwidth limitation from the photodiode.

I'm more concerned about the falling edge's behaviour, and wonder if anyone could suggest any possible ways of improvements.

Please also see below for the setup of the experiment:
[image]

Where the small white box with a circular opening is where the VCSEL's emitting.

Comment: Thorlabs does mention bad rc effects when the incident beam isn’t well centred (https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=1295&pn=DET10C2 , bottom of page). Is your laser well centred on the detector?

Comment: How were plots acquired? The time scale and amplitude scale have no units. Of more concern, what impedance terminated the far end of the cable (off to left in photo) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely an effect caused by the photodiode than by the VCSEL. To be sure, check if you see the same result when monitoring the internal photodiode in the VCSEL package.

As mentioned in comments, there is a warning in the ThorLabs page describing the photodiode:

> Please note that inhomogeneities at the edges of the active area of the detector can generate unwanted capacitance and resistance effects that distort the time-domain response of the photodiode output. Thorlabs therefore recommends that the incident light on the photodiode is well centered on the active area.

This basically means that away from the designed active area of the photodiode, there is still a semiconductor structure capable of producing carriers when illuminated; but this region is not optimized for fast response like the active area is.

To avoid this problem, you can either restrict the optical beam to only fall on the active area of the the photodiode, or place an aperture in front of the photodiode to block off-center parts of the beam from reaching the detector.